# Access - Create/Update table based on primary tables selections

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have the following database structure in MS Access:

- Products - Contains ID (Primary Key), Product group (lookup from 'Product Group'), Retailer (lookup from 'Retailers'), Brand (lookup from 'Brand'), Name, Comments, Multiplier, Unit (lookup from 'Units'), Price and Usage (lookup from 'Usage')

[The following tables only have 'ID' and 'Product', 'Retailer' etc.]

- Product group
- Retailers
- Brand
- Units
- Usage

Now, every product can be used in one or many places (defined by 'Usage'), therefore the 'Usage' column in the 'Products' table allows multiple choices.

Every product has it's own multiplier, defined in the 'Multiplier' column of the 'Products' table.

Now to the actual problem:

I want to create a new table for every record in the 'Usage' table. In those tables I want a list of the products that are selected to be included in this group (as defined by the 'Usage' column in the 'Products' table - Observe the multiple choice). In this new table I want to be able to enter a multiplier that will be specific to where a certain product is used.

To recap: I want to be able to make a product list where every product has it's own multiplier and a secondary multiplier based on where the product is used. For easy accessing I also want to have tables where I can check what products are used at a specific place.

I hope you can get any sense of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you feel you need to create multiple tables? Have you read http://r937.com/relational.html or similar?

Comment: You need to do some reading. It is nearly always bad design to have multiple tables with more or less the same information. For example, if you have books for two authors, you would include a field that showed which author wrote the book.

Comment: No, I've not read that one. Only have some very basic knowledge of Access (or databases in general for that matter).

From what I've understood from the tutorials/guides I've been using, it is good praxis to group repetitive info so they can be used again.

In my case I will be having about 15 records in "Product groups", 10 in retailers, 10 units and 10 usage. I might have up to thousands of products, so multiple related tables should (to my understanding) make the database more manageable and consistent.

Comment: Hmm, then I've probably misunderstood something. The whole point of having multiple tables was to not have to enter same data over and over again...

Comment: You should not have to enter the same data. You need keys and look-up tables, probably, but **not** look-up fields.

Comment: Not sure that I understand... At the moment if I enter a new product, I go into "Products" table. There I select the Product group, Retailer, Brand and Unit from a drop-down menu. The Usage column is multiple choice (also a drop-down menu). So the only info I have to fill in manually is Name, Comments, Multiplier and Price.

Is this approach exactly the "look-up field"-approach you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve this puzzle...

I went back to the drawing board and reconstructed the database as follows:

```
Table: ProductBrand - (ID), BrandName
Table: ProductGroup - (ID), Name
Table: Supplier - (ID), Supplier_Name
Table: Units - (ID), Unit_Name
Table: UsageArea: (ID), UsageAreaName
Table: Products: (ID), ProductGroup.Name, Supplier.Name, ProductBrand.Name, Product_Name, Product_Comments, Product_BasisForCalculation, Product_Price, Units.Name, UsageArea.Name

Table: Multipliers - (Product.Name), (UsageArea.Name), Mulipliers.Multiplier
```

Column names within parenthesis are the primary keys (observe that "Multipliers" has a primary key made of two columns).

To fetch the information I need, I made Queries for every Usage Area. This queries the Supplier, Brand, Name, Comment, Calculation Basis, Price, Units and the Usage Area specific multiplier for that specific product.

If anyone has improvement ideas, I'm all ears :)